# How to write custom components in Ionic 2/3 without losing prepared css?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

When I write my own custom component like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'deletableItem',
  template: `
    <ion-checkbox item-right></ion-checkbox>
  `
})
export class DeletableItem {
  constructor() {}
}
```

And use it in some html view:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let bill of bills" (click)="openEdit(bill)">
      <ion-label text-left>{{bill.name}}</ion-label>
      <deletableItem></deletableItem>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

The looking of it is worse than just put it in parent's component view at once like this:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let bill of bills" (click)="openEdit(bill)">
      <ion-label text-left>{{bill.name}}</ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox item-right></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

All this because angular wrap this component's html code into  html tag. So we lose ionic components strengths (prepared css). Please do not suggest attributive component assignment like:

```
<ion-checkbox item-right deletableItem></ion-checkbox>
```

Because this is just simple example.

What is the best way to write custom components with ionic components inside without losing prepared css?

Comment: I have a similar [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43917454/ionic-2-ion-content-of-subcomponent-overlapped-by-ion-header) that you commented on. Just to understand the problem better, what is 'prepared css'? I couldn't find much about it.

Comment: @barney765 by prepared css I mean out of a box or built-in css from ionic framework.

Comment: I had this crazy idea that it might be possible to make `DeletableItem` a subclass of `Checkbox`. I think you'd need to copy the decorators to the new class as well, with the new selector name. You could then set the `item-right` property in the in the constructor. I know it's a terrible hack but perhaps it leads someone to come up with a solution.

Comment: "The looking of it is worse than just put it in parent's component view at once like this:" Huh?

Comment: Are you saying that nesting a custom component with item-right, loses it's styling when defined in a parent? If so, I'm wondering if you can see the CSS styles applied by item-right when component is stand alone, then remove item-right and use SASS/CSS instead in your custom component. Some screenshots would have worked wonders...

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots to elaborate... Before and after you insert components.

Answer (score 1):

You have to realise Ionic is using SASS and targets multiple platforms.
When you create your `<deletableItem></deletableItem>` you have should mimic what the ionic team did with ion-checkbox, and create you Sass files.

Check out the source folder [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/tree/master/src/components/checkbox) for `<ion-checkbox>`.

Define your own SASS for deleteableItem.

Furthermore, [on the Ionic website you can find the various SASS component/platform variables](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/).

I also gave a detailed related explanation, regarding *[Ionic CSS classes assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45216030/495157)* that may help you too.

You can also use Chrome *inspect* to see class assignments for ion-checkbox in the Developer tool, and compare them to the list on the Ionic website.