# Ionic 2, ion-content of subcomponent overlapped by ion-header

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a page with an `<ion-segment>` that I use as a Tab to switch between showing two different custom components:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Page</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>


  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="tab">
      <ion-segment-button value="section1">
        Section 1
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="section2">
        Section 2
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </ion-toolbar>

</ion-header>

<section1 *ngIf="tab === 'section1'"></section1>
<section2 *ngIf="tab === 'section2'"></section2>
```

The section components just have an `<ion-content>` with stuff in it.

The problem is that if I do it this way, the content of the pages will be overlapped by the header. I've tried different ways to avoid this without success.

One way is to put the `<ion-content>` into the page like this:

```
<ion-content>
  <section1 *ngIf="tab === 'section1'"></section1>
  <section2 *ngIf="tab === 'section2'"></section2>
</ion-content>
```

But this gives rise to a new problem. If the page contains an `<ion-refresher>` it will give this error: `Template parse errors: No provider for Content`. Moving the refresher into the page as well isn't an option.

How to solve this overlapping issue while still keeping the `<ion-content>` in the custom components?

Comment: What I can suggest ,You should use one ion-content for a complete page. Remove ion-content from the sections. ion-content adds lots of stuff to the DOM and using more than one can cause several issues like scrolling, infinite scroll problems

Comment: @SandeepSharma, I agree there should only be one ion-content per page. It is either in the Page, or in the Sections. So at any time there is only one active. The problem is, if I put it in the Section, I get the overlapping issue. If I put it in the Section, I cannot use a ion-refresher.

Comment: The problem is simillar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43825188/how-to-write-custom-components-in-ionic-2-3-without-losing-prepared-css). The main reason of overlapping because built-in css doesn't work correct if they wrapped by another html tag in your case <section1> or <section2>.